# share a table to other Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, microservices, chat

I have a microservice for the backend which is backed by Postgres.
I also have a microservice for a feature in the app which is Chats (messaging app), similar to Instagram for example.

Reasons why I have a different service for the chats feature :

1. I want to commit asynchronous commits for the Messages table (as well as other related tables such as Conversation table, Conversation_Participants table, etc.).
   Correct me if I'm wrong, but I cannot make some queries asynchronous, while have others to be synchronous. It's either this or that. So I need a separate DB for the chat feature.

   ** I could use maybe something like `SET LOCAL synchronous commit TO OFF:'` per each query but I'm assuming 
    that wouldn't be very wise, nor safe.
2. Alleviate the load from the main backend's microservice.

**The problem :**

In my main microservice, I have a table called `user_relations`, in which I can tell if a user blocked some other user.
Obviously, that is something that the Chat microservice should be aware of, so users won't be able to send messages to people that blocked them.
But how can the Chat microservice access that data?
Should I maintain a copy of the uer_relations table and then with each change in main service, I will send a gRPC request to the Chat service in order to update its own user_relations table accordingly?
Or is there a better solution?

Comment: What do you think enabling asynchronous commit will give you?

Comment: my thought was that in a constant series of chat messages between different users, where in each active conversation the messages can be sent in a very low interval (every second?) it should speed up the performance, or at least allow to carry the current architecture to a bit larget scale until I have to redesign the whole thing using more "exotic" approaches and databases. Am I wrong?

Comment: 1 insert per second is nothing to worry about with modern hardware. My laptop could probably sustain even 1000 inserts per second without any problems. When you start talking 20000 insert per second or more with hundreds of concurrent connections, then it's time to think about tuning. Asynchronous commit won't reduce the load on the disk, it only makes your application "_think_"  it's faster because it's done "later in the background".

Comment: I see.. so how would you go about this? in terms of tuning - what kind of tuning could help in the case you described, without the need to replace it with a different db? are you saying I should not make it a different microservice at all, or simply use the same one database that the main microservice uses? in case you do think a separate microservice is needed, how can I solve the problem with blocked users?

Comment: If the tables are so closely related they belong into the same database (using foreign keys to make sure they contain only consistent data). If you want you could use schemas (=namespaces) to logically separate tables for different "business cases" (or microservices)

Comment: ok, so it seems my safest bet is to share the same DB across between those two microservices. When I need to send a message to other participant in the conversation, should I make two roundtrips then - one to user_relations table to check that I'm even allowed to send that message (user not blocked) and then after that a query to insert the message itself ? how would that impact the capability of real-time messaging when the table of all messages grows really big?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211694/discussion-between-bvtp-and-a-horse-with-no-name).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [`asynchronous_commit`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/wal-async-commit.html) at multiple levels, including at the `user` or `transaction` levels (see the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-SYNCHRONOUS-COMMIT)), so it is possible to share the same table between services.

If you really want two DB, you can consider a link from DB2 to DB1, or even another service on DB1 allowing (or not) a communication between 2 users.

Comment: when you mentioned a link between DB2 to DB1, you meant that as simply sending gRPC calls from main service to the chat service in order to update its copy of user_relations table with each new 'block/unblock' event? (or even send that as a job in some message queue like rabbitmq/kafka)

Comment: no, more like the [Foreign Data Wrapper](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) that let you read (and more) the data on the remote DB

Comment: do you think I should make 2 dbs, or 2 services to use 1 mutual db? I don't want to pose unnecessary load on the main backend because of the chats feature

Comment: I would have 1 DB, but I would code everything cleanly so if I ever change my mind it becomes very simple to use distinct ones :-)